# Internal polygon formed by drawing diagonals in a regular polygon

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons, golden-ratio

In an n-sided (n>4) regular polygon, label the vertices `{0, 1, ..., n-1}`. For each vertex i, draw a pair of diagonals:

- from i to (i+2) mod n and
- from i to (i-2) mod n

*Question*: What is the ratio of the area of the internal polygon to the external polygon?

For n=5 and n=6, this process will result in the following diagrams. For the pentagon, the ratio would be `area(ONRQP)/area(CBFED)`.

[image]
<sub>(source: [uga.edu](http://intermath.coe.uga.edu/tweb/gwin1-01/luce/Actvty3/7030_activity_3_files/image005.gif))</sub>
[image]

*Background*: [This page](http://intermath.coe.uga.edu/tweb/gwin1-01/luce/Actvty3/7030_activity_3.htm) has a discussion about pentagons and notes that if CB=1 (unit length) then ON=1/$\phi^2$ where $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$ is the golden ratio. Since the area of a pentagon is proportional to the square of its side length ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon)), `area(ONRQP)/area(CBFED)` = 1/$\phi^4$ ~ 0.146.

But I don't know how to generalize it to a regular n-gon. It seems obvious that as `n` increases, the ratio approaches 1 but I wonder if there is a closed form expression as a function of `n`.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that the area is proportional to the the square of the side length, but it could be difficult to calculate the side lengths that are involved.

**Hint:** The area is proportionate to the distance from the center.

Let $ \omega$ be a $n$th root of unity, and $\omega^i$ be the vertices of the polygon.

What is the distance of a side of the regular polygon from the origin?

> $ | \frac{ \omega^i + \omega^{i+1} } { 2} |$

What is the distance of a diagonal of the regular polygon from the origin?

> $ | \frac{ \omega^{i} + \omega^{i+2} } {2}| $

Hence, the ratio of areas is

> $\left| \frac{ \omega^1+\omega^{-1}}{\omega^{\frac{1}{2}}+\omega^\frac{1}{2}} \right|^2 = ...$

Comment: Given $\omega^i$ as the vertices I can see that the length of a side of the polygon is |$\omega^i$ - $\omega^{i+1}$| and a similar expression for the diagonals. I don't know how to compute the distance of a side. Also, I just don't see how that will help me compute the areas.

Comment: @user2602740 The distance from the side to the origin is the distance from the midpoint of the side to the origin, namely $\frac{\omega^i + \omega^{i+1} } { 2} $. What about the distance from the diagonal to the origin?

Comment: As the number of sides increases and the ratio of inner area/outer area goes to 1, we are computing $\pi.$

Comment: @FredKline Can you please show me how we are computing pi?

Comment: ![http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Polygon_approximation_to_a_circle] should have a little info. Scroll down to _Polygon approximation to a circle_